# How do I use callback value in server-side React component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, callback

I'm having trouble using server-side React to display a list of players from my Mongo database.

My goal is to **NOT** use external libraries aside from `mongodb` and `react` because I'd like to learn the underlying concepts before I start implementing advanced solutions.

My code requires a module (`players.js`) and invokes a callback defined in `index.jsx` that should process the Mongo query results. These process results should be accessible by the component.

Here it is:

`players.js`

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost/collection';
var database;
var players;

module.exports = function(callback) {

    // Initialize collection
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        database = db;
        database.collection('players', findPlayers);
    });

    // This named callback function is here in case
    // I want to do anything else with the collection
    function findPlayers(err, collection) {
        collection.find({}, getCursor);
    }

    function getCursor(err, cursor) {
        cursor.toArray(function(err, players) {
            // Invoke callback with err and players array
            callback(err, players);

            // Close Mongo connection
            database.close();   
        });
    }
}
```

`index.jsx`

```
var React = require('react');
var players = require('./players');

// call module and pass processPlayers function
var competitors = players(processPlayers);

// with the query results, return some neat JSX code
function processPlayers(err, results) {
    return results.map(function(player) {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{ player.rank }</td>
                <td>{ player.name }</td>
            </tr>
        )
    });
}

// Create index component class
var Index = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return ( <main><table>{ competitors }</table></main> );
    }
});

// Export component
module.exports = Index;
```

I understand that in `index.jsx` I'm setting `competitors` to an undefined return, but that's because I am stuck. How do I set `competitors` to the mapped results?

Again, I am *NOT* looking for promises or the async library. *I want to learn the basics and proper code structure.* I'll even be glad to look at related library source code if provided.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the answer to my question.

The library I was using for the server-side version of React can be found [here](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views).

In the documentation, I found out that the `.jsx` views are synchronous and that it's recommended that I pass database query results in the route. This data will be exposed as a property in the component via `this.props`.

So... I went into my route file and changed the original code from this:

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
}
```

To this:

```
var players = require('../helpers/players');

module.exports = function (req, res) {
    // call to module with anonymous function callback
    players(function(err, results) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        // using arg from anonymous function and
        // passing as local variable
        res.render('index', {'players': results});
    })
};
```

And now my component render method looks like this...

```
render: function() {

    function createPlayerRows(player) {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{ player.rank }</td>
                <td>{ player.name }</td>
            </tr>           
        );
    }

    // `players` property provided by route
    // mapped array using callback function which
    // creates an array of JSX elements
    var players = this.props.players.map(createPlayerRows);

    return ( <main><table>{ players }</table></main> );
}
```

Not sure if it will help anyone out, but I am sure relieved.